# List of all files with PHP in a huge site

Tags: php

I need to do a list of all files on a server from an other server.

I don't have access to PHP config like maximum timeout of the remote server.
The maximum timeout could be very short like 30s. In some case, the following code gives a Timeout issue, because the iterator don't have enough time to get all the files.

```
public function getStructure($path)
    {
        $structure = new \stdClass();
        $structure->dirs = array();
        $structure->files = array();
        $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($iterator as $file)
        {
            if ($file->isDir())
            {
                $structure->dirs[] = $file->getRealpath();
            }
            else
            {
                $structure->files[] = $file->getRealpath();
            }
        }

        return $structure;
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to get the structure in multiple calls. Something like : myremotesite.com/api/v1/structrue?start=xxxx where start is the point where the last call stop.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly pretty sure he's using a stupid shared hosting service which doesn't allow execution time to be edited. (and in fact, many of them run a daemon which constantly monitor php scripts and run `kill -s SIGKILL pid` on any php script running for over 30 seconds. (byethost, 000webhost, freewebhost.com, and more) hell, even some premium PAID hosting providers do this, like proisp.no

Comment: Thank for the reply, as I said I don't have configuration access  to that remote server. This is why I'm looking for a full PHP solution. All ini_set(**) are also locked.

Comment: There is no way to get a directory iterator to start at a specific “position.” (And since the directory contents are returned in more or less random order, it would not make that much sense either.) The most you can do using this approach, is to “ignore” the first X entries by keeping a counter in your loop, and only do the “costly” operations (is_dir, getRealPath) for the files after that. (Plus break out of the loop, after the number of entries you want to handle in one round has been processed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you need a dir with save/resume functionality... i would probably implement it in SQLite, due to its synchronous-by-default nature.

since i was bored.. UNTESTED, but should work in theory. DO NOT try to implement beginTransaction() / commit() optimizations to this code, that would defeat the whole "synchronous and tolerates crashing at any moment" part of the code;

```
<?php 
//will return bool(true) when it's finished creating the database.
//should be timeout/unstable system resistant, 
//relying on SQLite's syncronous-by-default nature.
function dirToSQLite($dir,$sqldb){
    if(!is_readable($dir)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('argument 1 must be a readable dir, but is not readable.');      
    }
    if(!is_dir($dir)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('argument 1 is not a valid dir');
    }
$db=new PDO('sqlite:'.$sqldb,'','',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dir` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,`path` TEXT UNIQUE,`type` TEXT);');
$db->query('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `dir` (`path`,`type`) VALUES('.$db->quote($dir).',\'dirUnexplored\');');
$stm=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO `dir` (`path`,`type`) VALUES(:path,:type);');
$stmExplored=$db->prepare('UPDATE `dir` SET `type` = \'dir\' WHERE id = ? ');
$path='';
$type='';
$stm->bindParam(':path',$path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam(':type',$type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
while(true){
    $found=false;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT `id`,`path` FROM `dir` WHERE `type` = \'dirUnexplored\'') as $res)
    {
        $found=true;
        $di=new DirectoryIterator($res['path']);
        foreach($di as $file){
            if($file->isDot()){
                continue;
            } else
            if($file->isLink()){
                $type='link';
            } else
            if($file->isDir()){
                $type='dirUnexplored';
            } else
            if($file->isFile()){
                $type='file';
            } else
            {
                $type='unknown';
            }
            $path=$file->getPathname();
            $stm->execute();
        }
        $stmExplored->execute(array($res['id']));
    }
    if(!$found){
        break;
    }
}
return true;
}
if(true===dirToSqlite('/home/foo','homefoo.db3')){
echo "finished!";
}else {
throw new Exception();
}
```

then just keep calling that url until it returns the string "finished!", then you can download the SQLite database directly, no php involved in the download.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clever approach. I have already MySQL access so I'll use it.